# C++ Sorting Custom Objects in a list

Tags: c++, list, events, sorting, object

I am having trouble sorting a list of custom class pointers. The class I need to sort are events. These get assigned a random time and I need to do them in the right order.

```
#include <list>

Class Event{
public: 
float time; // the value which I need to sort them by
int type; // to indicate which event i'm dealing with

Event(float tempTime, int tempType)
{
    time = tempTime;
    type = tempType; 
}


int main(){

std::list<Event*> EventList;
list<Event*>::iterator it;

.........
```

If you could help me sort this out it would be much appreciated! I've been stuck on this for hours now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Since the list contains pointers, rather than objects, you'll have to provide a custom comparator to compare the objects they point to. And since you're using a `list`, you have to use its own `sort` method: the generic `std::sort` algorithm only works on random-access sequences.

```
EventList.sort([](Event * lhs, Event * rhs) {return lhs->time < rhs->time;});
```

or, if you're stuck in the past and can't use lambdas:

```
struct CompareEventTime {
    bool operator()(Event * lhs, Event * rhs) {return lhs->time < rhs->time;}
};

EventList.sort(CompareEventTime());
```

If the list contained objects (as it probably should), then it might make sense to provide a comparison operator instead:

```
bool operator<(Event const & lhs, Event const & rhs) {return lhs.time < rhs.time;}

std::list<Event> EventList;
//...
EventList.sort();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The last comment made me realize that I was using pointers without any reason. Thus I changed it and implemented your last solution and it is working perfectly now.  (btw. The last solution did give me an error of requiring only a single element in the operator function, So I deleted the lhs and used    this->  instead

Comment: @user2374868: Yes, you could make the operator a member function with a single argument, rather than my example of a non-member with two arguments.

Comment: For lists, use List.Sort()  and not std::Sort() Just realized this after an hour

Comment: @Mike Seymour you mentioned to define sort function by yourself but didn't defined you just defined comparator function or operator is this enough and I suppose we still need to include algorithm library to use sort? Correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should to that with [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). You can either make a custom comparator function that you pass as third argument to the `std::sort` function, or you can make a `<` operator overload for your class and `std::sort` will work naturally.

Comment: You mean `std::list<>::sort`.  You can't use `std::sort` on `std::list`, because it doesn't have random access iterators.

Comment: I have tried using a custom comparator function but it will not work for me. (And using list.sort) j