# Sorting a list of structs by an element

Tags: c++, list, sorting, struct

I have got a struct like below:

```
struct Man 
{
  string surname;
  string name;
  char sex;
  int birth_year;
  int age;
  Man * next;
};
```

How can I sort list alphabetically by surname?

I know how to do that by bubble sort with arrays, but can't handle with list :/

Comment: what "list" are you referring to? `std::vector`?

Comment: @m.s. He defined the structure as a node of a single-linked list.

Comment: `std::sort` comes to mind. Have you tried that, and if so, what was the problem? If this is a DIY linked list, consider just copying the data to a standard container and sorting that with `std::sort`. And if you don't want to do that, e.g. this is an exercise, well, try on merge stort. That's good for forward-only sequences.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf  He cannot apply std::sort for his list.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: You may be right. However, I can. ;-)

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf  You also can not because his list can have only forward iterators.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Sorting Custom Objects in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507519/c-sorting-custom-objects-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the `std::list::sort` work all you would need to do is overload the `<` operator of your class.

In your case this would look something like this

```
//n.b. untested code
bool operator< (const Man& other)
{
    toupper(this->surname) < toupper(other->surname);
}
```

You also could call the overload of `sort` wich takes a comp function as argument. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/).

Comment: @Nagendra NR Could you explain how he can apply std::sort to his list?!

Answer (score 0):

just advice, if the only thing you want to sort is surname, you could try to add this Nodes by the order of surname at the first place, then you don't need to sort it again, because it's made by sorting

Comment: I want sort whole Struct by surname

Comment: Then you could sort when adding, just like, you have a "a , c", you could directly insert to the middle of it. You might need the function of 'strcmp',and learn to add  to the top of the list and the middle of the list

Answer (score 0):

use std::map< string, Man >,   insert each element of your list into this map with surname as key, object of Man as value.   Elements of MAp are sorted based on key, so just iterate through the map to get the objects in the sorted order.

Comment: His assignment is to sort a list directly without using a map.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must to create std::vector or std::deque of your items.
2. Use std::sort.

Example:

```
std::vector<Man*> people;
Man* head = YOUR HEAD POINTER;
// Create vector from your list
while(head) { 
     people.push_back(head);
     head = head->next;  
} 
// sort vector
std::sort(people.begin(),people.end(), [](const Man* m1, const Man* m2) {
    return m1->surname < m2->surname;
});
```

Comment: Why does he must  to create std::vector or std:;deque when his assignment is to create a list?!

Comment: Sort the list is slower then vector.
And maybe he has a good reason to use your list instead of std::list.

Answer (score 0):

To sort the list you can build a new list from the existing list by inserting elements in the order in the new list from the existing list.

Here is a simplified example. Of course you need to add some more functions as for example a function that will delete all nodes of the list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <tuple>

struct Man 
{
    std::string surname;
    std::string name;
/*
    char sex;
    int birth_year;
    int age;
*/
    Man * next;
};

void push_front( Man * &head, const std::string &surname, const std::string &name )
{
    head = new Man { surname, name, head }; 
}

std::ostream & display( const Man *head, 
                        std::ostream &os = std::cout,
                        const char *delim = ", ")
{
    for ( const Man *tmp = head; tmp; tmp = tmp->next )
    {
        os << tmp->surname << ' ' << tmp->name << delim;
    }

    return os;
}

void sort( Man * &head )
{
    Man *new_head = nullptr;

    while ( head != nullptr )
    {
        Man *node = head;
        head = head->next;

        Man *prev = nullptr;
        for ( Man *tmp = new_head; 
              tmp && !
              ( std::tie( node->surname, node->name ) < std::tie( tmp->surname, tmp->name ) ); )
        {
            prev = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }            

        if ( prev == nullptr )
        {
            node->next = new_head;
            new_head = node;
        }
        else
        {
            node->next = prev->next;
            prev->next = node;
        }
    }

    head = new_head;    
}

int main() 
{
    Man *head = nullptr;

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    const size_t N = 10;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        push_front( head, 
                   std::string( 1, 'A' + std::rand() % ( 'Z' - 'A' + 1 ) ),
                   std::string( 1, 'A' + std::rand() % ( 'Z' - 'A' + 1 ) ) );
    }

    display( head ) << std::endl;

    sort( head );

    display( head ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Y P, D X, K J, R G, K J, X V, V I, X M, C K, A Y, 
A Y, C K, D X, K J, K J, R G, V I, X M, X V, Y P,
```

Instead of the function `std::tie` you may compare simply surnames of two nodes.

Take into acccount that it would be better to split your structure into two parts. For example

```
struct Man 
{
    std::string surname;
    std::string name;
    char sex;
    int birth_year;
    int age;
};

struct Node 
{
    Man person; 
    Node * next;
};
```