# sorting an array and maintaining element's old index

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++11, structure

I have an array A:

```
A     =   [10 11 3 15 8 7]
index =    0   1 2  3 4 5
```

I want to sort this array.After sorting I want the information of old index.For this I can create a structure like this.

```
struct VnI{
  int value;
  int index;
};
```

sorting the array of structure with respect to value solve my problem.But I want to know that is it possible to solve this using **sort** or any other function in C++11.

I have tried this way:

```
struct VnI{
int V;
int I;
};

bool comparator(VnI x,VnI y){
    if(x.V < y.V)
        return true;
    return false;
}
int maximumGap(const vector<int> &A) {
   vector<VnI> B;
   for(int i = 0;i < A.size();i++){
      B[i].I = i;
      B[i].V = A[i];
}
sort(B.begin(),B.end(),comparator);
for(int i = 0;i < B.size();i++){
    cout<<B[i].I<<" "<<B[i].V<<endl;
  }
}
```

But I got runtime error.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

This code is wrong:

```
vector<VnI> B;  

for(int i = 0;i < A.size();i++){
   B[i].I = i;
   B[i].V = A[i];
}
```

When you write `B[i]`, it assumes that `B` is *at least* of size `i+1`. Since the maximum value of `i` (which you used an index to `B`) is `A.size()-1`. The assumption in your code is that `B` is at least of size `A.size()`.  **This assumption is wrong** — the fact is that `B` is of size `0`.

Unfortunately `operator[]` of `std::vector` doesn't check for *out of range* index. If you use `at()`, the code will throw `std::out_of_range` exception:

```
vector<VnI> B;  

for(int i = 0;i < A.size();i++){
   B.at(i).I = i;
   B.at(i).V = A[i];
}
```

Now this would throw `std::out_of_range` exception.

Anyway, one simple fix could be this:

```
 vector<VnI> B (A.size());  //initialize B with the size of A.

 for(int i = 0;i < A.size();i++){
    B[i].I = i;
    B[i].V = A[i];
 }
```

However, I'd suggest this solution:

```
 vector<VnI> B;      
 B.reserve(A.size()); 

 for(int i = 0;i < A.size(); i++){
    B.emplace_back(i, A[i]);
 }
```

I'd also suggest you read more about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), especially the following functions:

- `size()`
- `capacity()`
- `resize()`
- `reserve()`
- `push_back()`
- `operator[]`
- `at()`
- `emplace_back()`
- and all the constructors.

**Also, learn to naming your variables properly and be consistent with it.**

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

do you pefer to use vector and pair?

each pair has "first" and "second", put "first"=value to sort,"second"=original index, create a pair for each element and put them into vector to sort:

```
int N[]={10,11,3,15,8,7};
std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > v;
//create pair for each element
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(N)/sizeof(int);i++){
    //first is value of array,second is original index
    v.push_back(std::make_pair(N[i],i));
}

//sort the vector of pair
sort(v.begin(),v.end());

//get original index from second of pair
for(std::pair<int,int>& p : v){
    std::cout << p.first << ":" << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

output

```
3:2
7:5
8:4
10:0
11:1
15:3
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally what is done is the opposite... i.e. given an array `x` of elements compute an array of integers `ix` so that `x[ix[i]]` appears to be sorted under a certain criteria.

This allows representing the container with different orderings without actually having to move/copy the elements.

With C++11 this can easily be done using lambdas:

```
// Build the index vector ix
std::vector<int> ix(x.size());
for (int i=0,n=x.size(); i<n; i++) ix[i] = i;

// Sort ix according to the corresponding values in x
// (without touching x)
std::sort(ix.begin(), ix.end(),
          [&x](int a, int b) { return x[a] < x[b]; });
```

This `ix` index array is what you are asking for (i.e. the "old" position of an element: `ix[i]` is where the `i`-th element of the sorted list was in the original array) and there is no need to modify the input array.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to sort a list of custom objects, answerd here:

[SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507519/c-sorting-custom-objects-in-a-list)

Once you list the `list` of `VnI` objects you can then access there old index's through the `I` member that I presume is the index.